# Title is missing in 1st boxplot when using a for loop

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to plot 16 boxplots, using a for loop. My problem is, that the 2nd title is plotted on the first plot, the 3rd title on the second plot and so forth.

Does anyone have a guess on, what I am doing wrong?

[image]

My code is the following:

```
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Sweden"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Sweden"],title(main = "Sweden"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Norway"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Norway"],title(main = "Norway"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Denmark"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Denmark"],title(main = "Denmark"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Finland"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Finland"],title(main = "Finland"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Iceland"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Iceland"],title(main = "Iceland"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Belgium"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Belgium"],title(main = "Belgium"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Netherlands"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Netherlands"],title(main = "Netherlands"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Luxembourg"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Luxembourg"],title(main = "Luxembourg"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="France"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="France"],title(main = "France"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Italy"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Italy"],title(main = "Italy"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Spain"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Spain"],title(main = "Spain"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Portugal"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Portugal"],title(main = "Portugal"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Germany"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Germany"],title(main = "Germany"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Austria"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Austria"],title(main = "Austria"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Ireland"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Ireland"],title(main = "Ireland"))
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="UK"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="UK"],title(main = "UK"))
```

Comment: use a loop or equivalent or you won't enjoy summer a lot this year ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could replace all your lines *and* fix your problem:

```
for (i in data$countryname)
  boxplot(distance~alliance, subset(data, countryname==i), main=i)
```

But that's hard to verify without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) or some of your `data.frame`.

Comment: awesome, but for loop is missing curly braces

Comment: @Edward: no need for braces when what follows `for` (but not only `for`) is a single command

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html), you should be assigning a title to your boxplots by making explicit calls to the function `title()`, rather than as a parameter in the call to `boxplot()`.  The first two calls to generate your boxplots should look something like the following:

```
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Sweden"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Sweden"])
title(main = "Sweden")
boxplot(data$distance[data$countryname=="Norway"]~data$alliance[data$countryname=="Norway"])
title(main = "Norway")
```

Comment: just `boxplot(..., main="your_title")` would work as fine?